# What do the values in a function do in C?

Tags: c, function

I am trying to understand functions in C programming! Lets say I have the following functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fun_1(int num1, int num2);
int main(void) {

        int num1;

        printf("How many numbers? \n");

        num1 = fun_1(1,10);

        printf("Value is %d \n", num1);
}

int fun_1(int num1, int num2) {

        int intValue;

        if (num1 < 1 || num2 > 10) {

                printf("Wrong Number \n");

                while (num1 < 1 || num2 > 14) {
                        printf("Enter number between 1 and 10: ");
                        scanf("%d", &intValue);
                }
        return intValue;
        }
}
```

I don't understand what this line:`num1 = fun_1(1,10);` is doing in the function!
What does this line represent? Before this example I had not seen any function with value but only with variables for example like this:

```
value = fun_1(num1, num2);
```

Comment: You assign the return value of `fun_1` to `num1`. You should read a basic book about C.

Comment: But you are using a similar function call in `printf ("Wrong number\n")`. There is no requirement in C to pass only *variables*.

Comment: If you notice the return of `fun_1` is type `int`. So `num1 = fun_1(1,10);` simply assigns the integer returned from `fun_1` to `num1`. (No different that `a = b` where `a` is *num1* and `b` is *fun_1*.)

Comment: Is your `fun_1` correct? It looks like it will either run into an infinite loop or return an uninitialized value.

Comment: @ZoffDino or it returns nothing like in this case, because the `if` is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, the arguments to functions are *expressions*. Expressions come in many different forms. They can be variables, like in

```
 value = fun_1(num1, num2);
```

or they can be constants, like in

```
 value = fun_1(1, 12);
```

or even involve operators with other expressions:

```
 value = fun_1(fun_1(42, 1) * 3, sizeof "foo");
```

Note that the expressions must have a compatible *type*. Functions taking integral values don't take string literals or pointers. If you buy just one book for learning C, it should be *The C Programming Language*, 2nd ed., by Kernighan and Ritchie.

Answer (score 1):

Its just like the examples below.

```
int x, a = 2, b = 4;

x = a + b;   //this uses variables
```

and

```
int x;

x = 2 + 4; //this is using constants
```

---

Either passing the value using variables, (`num1` and `num2`), or passing them directly, (`1` and `10`). Its the same.

---

```
num1 = fun_1(1,10);
```

This means that whatever `fun_1()` returns, will get saved in `num1` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The line `num1 = fun_1(1,10);` is calling the function `fun_1`, with arguments 1 and 10, then assigning `num_1` to its return value.

Literals can be function arguments, as well as variables. The function only sees the value of whatever arguments you pass it, so it's effectively the same as passing two variables with equivalent values.

Comment: I suggest replacing "Constants" by "Literals." Constants also describe `const int`s, IMO.